# How to set a custom number of backup backend servers in HAproxy?

Tags: server, backup, haproxy

Let's say I have 3 main servers and 3 backup servers. I want HAproxy to replace a main server with a backup server as soon as it goes down.

To elaborate, let's say Main Server 1 goes down, HAproxy will then still continue to use 3 servers in total, where 2 will be main and 1 will be backup. Similarly, if 2 main server goes down, HAproxy will still use a total of 3 servers, 1 from main and 2 from backup.

Also, once the main server is active again, HAproxy should stop using the backup and switch back to the main server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [backup](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.3/configuration.html#5.2-backup) directive on the server line and [option allbackups](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.3/configuration.html#4-option%20allbackups) in the specific section.

You maybe can also add the [weight](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.3/configuration.html#5.2-weight) for the server to define which backup server should be used in priority order.